# Why am I getting this error about "string indices must be integer"?

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to find the total number of players by counting the unique screen names. 
    # Dependencies
    import pandas as pd

```
# Save path to data set in a variable
df = "purchase_data.json"

# Use Pandas to read data
data_file_pd = pd.read_json(df)
data_file_pd.head()
```

[image]

```
# Find total numbers of players
player_count = len(df['SN'].unique())

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-94bf0ee04d7b> in <module>()
  1 # Find total numbers of players
----> 2 player_count = len(df['SN'].unique())

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: `df` is a string

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post.. I will avoid posting a picture next time. I wasn't sure what was the best way to show my data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the original data, this is guess work.  But I think you might want something like this:

```
# Save path variable (?)
json_data = "purchase_data.json"

# convert json data to Pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_json(json_data)
df.head()
len(data_file_pd['SN'].unique())
```

Comment: I tried that too but it didn't work. I appreciate the input though.

Answer (score 0):

simply if you are getting this error while connecting to schema. then at that time close the web browser and kill the Pg Admin Server and restart it. then it will be work perfectly